# How to add rows to a .csv file

Tags: julia

I need to append rows to a .csv file. Each row contains a vector of integers.  Vectors to be added are generated on the fly and I cannot tell in advance how many rows will be added.
I tried to do the following, but it doesn't seem to create a .csv file, nor does it contain each element on a separate row.

```
s = open( "testfile.txt",  "a")

for i in 1:5

  x = rand(Int8, 10)
  writecsv( s, x)

end

close(s)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, you know how to create or over-write a csv file using this:

```
x = [1 2 ; 3 4 ; 5 6]
filePath = "/someAbsolutePath/temp1.csv"
writecsv(filePath, x)
```

When you want to append a new row (or multiple rows in one hit), you can also use `writecsv` but first you need to explicitly open the file in append mode, and then set the resulting file-identifier as the first argument to `writecsv`. Continuing the example above:

```
fid1 = open(filePath, "a")
writecsv(fid1, [7 8])
close(fid1)
```

I don't think `writecsv` will automatically `close` the file upon completion when the first input is a file-identifier, so the final `close` statement is very important. Alternatively, you can use the version proposed by @ShaoWeiTeo in the comments to get an automatic `close`.

Comment: We can also use the `open(f::Function, command, mode::AbstractString="r", stdio=DevNull)` version that automatically close the connection after the write happens. I prefers that more thn manual closing, and is a more Julian way to open files I think...

Comment: Thanks Colin and ShaoWei for your answers. This was what I was looking for.  Much appreciated!
I now also learned that writecsv() uses the UNIX philosophy for new lines, also on my Windows system.